# How to take input in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am taking user input for the addition of two numbers in typescript using following code:

```
 function rotatedString(S1,S2){
    return S1+S2;
}

    function processData() {
        //INPUT[uncomment & modify if required]
    var temp = gets().trim('\n').split('\n');
        var S1 = temp[0];
        var S2 = temp[1];
        
        //OUTPUT[uncomment & modify if required]
        console.log(rotatedString(S1,S2));
    }
    processData();
```

It throws me following error on : https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Parameter 'S1' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Parameter 'S2' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Cannot find name 'gets'.

Please help me out to take user input in TypeScript

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your exact problem? The link shows a general webpage, not a specific error as far as I can tell

Comment: Have you tried adding type specifications for `S1` and `S2`?  Where is `gets` defined?  It's not really clear what specifically you're asking.

Comment: `Cannot find name 'gets'.` What is `gets` in your context and are you sure it exists?

Comment: JS/TS does not have gets function. Maybe you should use Node.js where you can found `readline` function - https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Comment: I'm using gets to take an input 
var S1:any = parseInt(temp[0]);
    var S2:any = parseInt(temp[1]);

I tried this as well

Comment: Are you developing a command-line app or a web app? What kind of input are we talking? Did you mean to import `gets` from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use libraries like [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) in order to wait for a user prompt

It has also a lot of useful methods for terminal "graphics" and data handling!